# how to add icon to ng2-material dialog box?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a dialog box that im presenting when something happens, this is the code for it:

```
 public showMessageDialog(message) {
    let config = new MdDialogConfig()
      .title('Dialog Box:')
      .textContent(message)
      .ok('Got it') .;

    this.dialog.open(MdDialogBasic, this.element, config);
  }
```

Now I have some emoji icon I want to add to it when the box is triggered.

so from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This for Angular Material 1, but the concept should be the same for AM2.

You would have to use a custom dialog to achieve that - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/zByvYB?editors=1100)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="md-padding dialogdemoBasicUsage" id="popupContainer" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div class="dialog-demo-content" layout="row" layout-wrap="" layout-margin="" layout-align="center">
    <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAdvanced($event)">
      Custom Dialog
    </md-button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="dialog1.tmpl.html"><md-dialog aria-label="Mango (Fruit)"  ng-cloak>
        <md-dialog>
          <form>
            <md-dialog-content>
              <div class="md-dialog-content">
              <p class="md-title"> Dialog Box: </p>
              <div>
                <p> Some message </p>
                <img style="width:100px"  src="...">
              </div>
              </div>
            </md-dialog-content>

            <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
              <span flex></span>
              <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="answer('Got it')">
               Got it
              </md-button>
            </md-dialog-actions>
          </form>
        </md-dialog>
    </script>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia) {
  $scope.status = '  ';
  $scope.customFullscreen = false;

  $scope.showAdvanced = function(ev) {
    var useFullScreen = false;

    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose:true,
      fullscreen: useFullScreen
    })
    .then(function(answer) {
      $scope.status = answer;
    }, function() {
      $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
    });
  };

});

function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.hide = function() {
    $mdDialog.hide();
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
  };

  $scope.answer = function(answer) {
    $mdDialog.hide(answer);
  };
}
```